# trouble with Geany in Ubuntu Groovy Gorilla

Tags: python, geany

I'm a total novice in Python. My OS is Ubuntu Groovy Gorilla, Python version 3.8.6. I try to learn it using the book "crash course programming in python". I followed the instructions found in the first chapter of the book to the letter. I use Geany, as recommended. The programming is *print ("hello python world!")*. Then I press F5 to start the program in Geany. I get the following as result: /tmp/geany_run_script_5MD6V0.sh: 7: python: not found

---

(program exited with code: 127)
Press return to continue
What's the problem?

I also use Mu. And it executed the program without trouble. Is there something going on in Geany? What did I overlook?

Comment: Does it work from the commandline/terminal? As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Newer versions of Ubuntu come without Python 2 and the `python` command. Python 3 is used as `python3`. There's a package call something like `python-is-python3` (AFAIR) that will make Python 3 startable as `python`.

Comment: Dear Klaus D., Thanks for your answer. You are talking about a package call. How does it work? Where can I find it? How can I install it? Should I go to the terminal of Linux and use a command code? Or should I install it in Geany? (remember, I'm a total novice)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have Python installed on your system (e.g. by trying python3 on terminal or vitrifying with package management tool). You can adjust the command Geany is calling by going to »Build«->»Set Build Commands« -- There you can set the commands used. More detailed information can be found at [documentation](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#set-build-commands).

Answer (score 0):

replace `python` with `python3` for Compile and Execute labels

**Compile**

```
python -m py_compile "%f" ---> python3 -m py_compile "%f"
```

**Execute**

```
python "%f" ---> python3 "%f".
```